# New to batch code: Copy to specific folder starting from orange***

Tags: batch-file, random, copy, directory

Forgive me for the easy question but i want to code a program for copying to a specific location folder starting from orange***

for example :

C:\orange1

c:\orange12.531.1325

No other folder is there startin from orange

edit: I want to Copy to the above example folders any file using command prompt

Comment: command prompt (.bat-.cmd )

Comment: In the future, please put that information in the question. What do you mean starting from orage***?

Comment: what is so hard to understand?

Comment: You want to copy every folder that starts with orange?

Comment: "random" does not seem an appropriate tag, unless you are asking for random comments.

Comment: I WANT TO COPY A FILE  TO A FOLDER STARTING FROM ORANGE AND ENDING TO A RANDOM NAME AND THAT FODER (STARTING FROM ORANGE AND ENDING TO A RANDOM NAME) IS THE ONLY FOLDER IN THAT LOCATION

Comment: Please remain polite and patient. Other users are trying to help you out with your problem, so please answer their information requests politely. Remember that everyone who spends time trying to help you out is doing so freely, and on their own time.

Comment: i think i have answered the questions i have been asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a for loop through a directory listing - assuming you're running this from the directory that you want to move the files from:

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set copyTo=C:\Example

for /f %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (
    set fname=%%a
    if "!fname:~0,6!"=="orange" copy !fname! !copyTo!
)
```